# Show $\int_0^1|x'(t)|^2 dt \leq M_2$ given that $\int_0^1|x'(t)|^2-|x| dt \leq M_1$ (using Hoelders inequality)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, inequality

I am trying to prove the following statement:
$\int_0^1|x'(t)|^2-|x(t)| dt \leq M_1$ for some $M_1$, implies $\int_0^1|x'(t)|^2 dt \leq M_2$ for some $M_2$. Furthermore it is given that $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=1$.

The only assumption I make is that $x(t)$ is absolutely continuous, so one can write $x(t)=\int_0^tx'(s)ds$.

What I have so far:

$M_1 \geq  \int_0^1|x'(t)|^2-|x(t)| dt $ =$ \int_0^1|x'(t)|^2-|\int_0^tx'(s)ds|dt \geq \int_0^1|x'(t)|^2-\int_0^t|x'(s)|dsdt$

Now using Hoelders inequality in the form $\int_0^t|x'(s)|ds\leq (\int_0^t|x'(s)|^2ds)^\frac{1}{2}$ we get to

$M_1 \geq  \int_0^1|x'(t)|^2 - (\int_0^t|x'(s)|^2ds)^\frac{1}{2}dt$.

One could then use $\sqrt(x) \leq 1+x$, to end up with $M_1+1 \geq  \int_0^1|x'(t)|^2 - (\int_0^t|x'(s)|^2ds)dt$

How could one proceed from here? I have tried now for several hours now but could not see any way to get to the conclusion. Or is there some completely different way?

Best

Answer (score 1):

Answer to original version, where the condition $x(0)=x(1)=0$ was left out:

Saying you want this for "arbitrary" constants makes little sense. You want to show that given $M_1$ there exists $M_2$ such that $\int(|x'|^2-|x|)\le M_2$ implies $\int|x'|^2\le M_1$.

This is more or less obviously false. Given $M_1$, choose $y$ so $\int|y'|^2>M_1$. For any $M_2$ there exists a constant $c$ so if $x=y+c$ then $\int(|x'|^2-|x|)<M_2$ although $\int|x'|^2=\int|y'|^2>M_1$.